# Connecting to Elasticsearch - Amazon Elasticsearch service - IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I have selected "Allow access to one or more AWS accounts or IAM users"

My access policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/elastic"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:123456789:domain/elastic-cluster/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created an IAM profile -

```
user - elastic 
password -hisdfdsfds
Access key Id - sdsfdssdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsd
Secret Access Key - sdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfds
```

when I try to connect

```
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = array (
    'search-elastic-cluster-sdfsdfsdfs.eu-east.es.amazonaws.com:80',                 
    );

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```

It throws the following error:

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:dsfdsfsdfsdsd:domain/elastic-cluster/sdsfsfds/sdfdsfdssd/_search"}
```

I found  it can be accessed by signed version 4 signature requests. I tried doing it, but could not . Maybe the way is wrong.

I would be happy if some one suggests ideas in creating signed version 4 request to elasticsearch domain. An example  using parameters I stated above would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was having similar troubles, but with a different code (using boto2). I checked all user permissions and it turned out to be the ES permissions (similar to security groups) that was denying the IP I was using.

Answer (score 1):

The application needs to sign the requests going to Elasticsearch. The AWS SDK for your language of choice should have a method which creates the credentials for the sign request.

When you provide your requests with the credentials, it should be ok and good to go.

This is a code snippet using the javascript sdk:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');

var esDomain = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: 'yoursearchdomain.region.amazonaws.com',
    index: 'myindex',
    doctype: 'mytype'
};

var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(esDomain.endpoint);

var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

    req.method = 'POST';
    req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
    req.region = esDomain.region;
    req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
    req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    req.body = doc;

var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req , 'es'); 
    signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());
    
    var send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
    send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
        var respBody = '';
        httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            respBody += chunk;
        });
        httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ' + respBody);
            context.succeed('Lambda added document ' + doc);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        context.fail('Lambda failed with error ' + err);
    });
```