# How to index data on aws Elasticsearch with nodejs elasticsearch package

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I was working with Elasticsearch and I've created a domain on was ES service and trying to index mongoDB data on AWS. But as my domain is password protected I cannot index data there. The node script that I'm using was able to index mongoDB data on my localhost(which didn't have any password) so I'm sure my script is okay.

Here is the connections function that i'm using to connect elasticsearch.

```
const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: config.elasticsearch.url + '' + config.elasticsearch.port,
  requestTimeout: 6 * 350 * 25000,
  requestTimeout: Infinity,
  keepAlive: false,
  // log: 'debug',
});
```

My config

```
  "elasticsearch": {
    "url": "HTTP://localhost",
    "port": "9200",
    "elasticsearchIndices": {
      "collection": {
        "index": "business",
        "type": "location",
        "collectionName": "collection"
      }
    }
  },
```

Well, I just need to put the **username** and **password** here somewhere, but I don't know where to put it. On the official documentation, it says to put the **username** and **password** on the elasticsearch connection string like

```
const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: config.elasticsearch.url + '' + config.elasticsearch.port,
  auth: 'username:password',
  requestTimeout: 6 * 350 * 25000,
  requestTimeout: Infinity,
  keepAlive: false,
  // log: 'debug',
});
```

but this is not working either. Please if anyone has a solution please help me with this.
Regards

Comment: You need to use the AWS sdk node.js package in order to sign your request as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node

Comment: @Val thanks for your reply. but is there any other way so that I could just index my MongoDB collection. here the AWS-SDK is importing JSON files one by one. I need to put a lot of data inside the indices.

Comment: You can use the `_bulk` endpoint instead. You can refer to this answer by @joe https://stackoverflow.com/a/61175516/4604579 which shows exactly how this works

Comment: @Val
Hello again, now this error shows up `Error: Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: search-johukum-npp7rd7lsyfvol7gw2wxrb4omi.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Your URL needs to be `https://`, not `http://`

Comment: Also see if this helps: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1998