# axios put request for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I have been battling for a few days to follow an article . This is not new to me but not my strong point.
Ive managed to get my http request working but I think I need to add auth to it. here is the code.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const host = 'https://search-data-ds-42456788224444444444444444.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com';
const index = 'msgsdatastream';
const type = 'msgs';
const url = `${host}/${index}/${type}/`;
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (const record of event.Records) {
    const id = 1;
    if (record.eventName == 'REMOVE') {
      await axios.delete(url + id);
      return 'Item removed';
    } else {
      const document = record.dynamodb.NewImage;
      console.log('Adding document');
      console.log(document);
      await axios.put(url + id, document);
    }
    count += 1;
  }
  return `Successfully processed ${count} records.`;
};
```

This is inside my Lambda function

Here is the cloudwatch logs.

```
    2021-02-05T12:52:05.386Z    13782564-f0fc-4a6d-892a-c00c9e880bd1    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "message": "Request failed with status code 403",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 403\n    at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)",
    "config": {
        "url": "https://search-msgs-ds-rt5io3veb4k4m5vtglmg43frxu.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/msgsdatastream/msgs/1",
        "method": "put",
        "data": "{\"Area\":{\"S\":\"Lotus\"},\"id\":{\"S\":\"2\"},\"Name\":{\"S\":\"Romano\"}}",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.1",
            "Content-Length": 59
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1
    }
}
```

I am failing forward on this one. editing as I go along. Please could you direct me in how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not use JS client Elasticsearch provides? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html

Comment: Hi, Im following thi tutorial https://medium.com/swlh/loading-data-to-aws-elasticsearch-with-dynamodb-streams-and-lambda-77e52b9c797.

this is the only reason why. im not a developer but i have an idea for something so youtube and forums like this is guiding me. Ill give the link you attached a go as well

Comment: @romanobrooks Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61175516/8160318) regarding ES Lambda auth and look for `AWS.Signers`.